# How to get Display Mode of a product variation in hook_commerce_form_add_to_cart_form_alter?

Tags: commerce, hooks

I want to alter a product display using hook_form_alter as below:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function HOOK_form_commerce_order_item_add_to_cart_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  $product = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()->getPurchasedEntity();

// THIS WHERE I want something like 
  if($product->viewMode() == 'compact') {
     // do something...
  }
}
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind figured out myself,

I found the answer to get the view_mode you need to access storage of form stage using following code.

```
$form_state->getStorage()['view_mode'];
```

This will return string based on which view mode the form is attached to.

i.e, "defualt" or "compact" etc...